# Page loading Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, loading

I'm doing a personal project in angular, and I wanted to make a page that whenever I open the site, this screen appears for a couple of seconds and then redirects to the home component.
Or a way to create a page to appear for a couple of seconds while the site loads in the background

```js
app.routing ***


const routes: Routes = [
  {path: "", redirectTo:"home", pathMatch:"full"},
  {path: "home", component: HomeComponent},
  {path: ":id", component: OverviewComponent},
  {path: ":id/:id", component: OverviewComponent},
  {path: ":id/:id/:id", component: OverviewComponent},
  {path: ":id/:id/:id/:id", component: OverviewComponent},
  {path: ":id/:id/:id/:id/:id", component: OverviewComponent},
  {path: "**", redirectTo:"home"}
  
];
```

Comment: If you are planning a loading page, you can create these inside `<app-root></app-root>` of index.html

Comment: Dude, what an incredible idea kkk, I did and it worked, but how to hold the page for a couple of seconds?
Like, a time before heading to the 'home' route

Comment: Have you tried looking at [APP_INITIALIZER](https://angular.io/api/core/APP_INITIALIZER)?

Comment: What kind of hold? But i think the app initilizer will solve to you /\

Comment: So that time to display a gif before redirecting to the home component.
I'll take a look at this topic
thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

Your index.html can be like

```
<body>
  <app-root>
    <img class="logo" src="assets/logo.jpg">
  </app-root>
</body>
```

So, while you're loading the app the "logo" is showed

You can also change your main.ts to wait before bootstrap the aplication

```
const timer=new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
  resolve("ready")
}, 2000)
})
timer.then(_=>{
  platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule).then(ref => {
    // Ensure Angular destroys itself on hot reloads.
    if (window['ngRef']) {
      window['ngRef'].destroy();
    }
    window['ngRef'] = ref;
  
    // Otherwise, log the boot error
  }).catch(err => console.error(err));
})
```